# Double index numbering to linear numbering

Tags: python, indexing

I am struggling with a problem - please forgive me for my bad English. I am currently writing some script in Python where I need to manipulate list and convert them.
I want to convert a double numbering to another numbering where only one index is used.

If `n` is the first index of my double numbering and `m` the second one, what is the expression `L(n, m) = idx` which permits to pass from (here `n_max = 3` but I want a general rule) :

```
[n, m] => [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

and so on to

```
idx => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

? It clearly depend on n_max but I am searching for a while and don't find any reliable expression or script.

For example, if the `[n, m]` had the following structure :

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

the searched expression would be :

```
idx = L(n, m) = n * (n + 1) / 2 + m
```

Any help will be appreciated, even little hints or links :)
Thanks ! I already searched on the web and on this website but didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
It was the following:

```
$ idx = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} l_{max} - i $
```